# shell script to combine PDF's in a folder and use pdf file name as bookmark

Tags: linux, shell-script, pdf, pdftk, bookmarks

I have a series of folders with employee names and their documents in pdf format. I want to merge and create a single PDF file with pdf documents indexed as bookmarks in pdf file.

I tried using PDFTK to merge the pdf's in folder, however the output does not bookmark.

Answer (score 1):

I created a script for this purpose. You may choose to keep `.pdf` extension by modify heredoc.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

pages=1
bookmarks="bookmarks.txt"
tmp_pdf="tmp.pdf"

if [ -f $bookmarks ]; then
    read -p "Do you want to overwrite the bookmarks file? [y/N] " -n 1 -r
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
        rm $bookmarks
    else
        echo "Aborting..."
        exit 1
    fi
fi

for pdf in *.pdf; do
    cat <<- EOF >> $bookmarks
    BookmarkBegin
    BookmarkTitle: ${pdf%.pdf}
    BookmarkLevel: 1
    BookmarkPageNumber: $pages
    EOF
    page_number=$(pdftk $pdf dump_data | rg 'NumberOfPages: ' | awk '{print $2}')
    pages=$(($pages + $page_number))
done

pdftk *.pdf cat output $tmp_pdf
pdftk $tmp_pdf update_info $bookmarks output final.pdf

rm -f $tmp_pdf
rm -f $bookmarks
```

The idea is:

- Create a pdftk info file which contains bookmark
- Call pdftk cat to concatenate them
- Call updateinfo to add bookmarks
- Remove temp files, done.

Comment: thank you for your script, i am able to write this bit:tempPDF=`mktemp`
for i in *.pdf
do
    bookmarkTitle=`basename "$i" .pdf`
    bookmarkInfo="BookmarkBegin\nBookmarkTitle: $bookmarkTitle\nBookmarkLevel: 1\nBookmarkPageNumber: 1"
    pdftk "$i" update_info_utf8 <(echo -en $bookmarkInfo) output $tempPDF verbose
    mv $tempPDF "$i"
done

Comment: I keep trying to use this script, but I get a `33: parse error near \n`, is there supposed to be more indentation in the `pdf` for loop?

Comment: Actually, I got it to work by removing the indentation for the whole `EOF` block.